# Conditionals bugged on Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, if-statement

I am teaching a simple comparisons on programming, but I have found something odd when I am trying to list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, when I add the following conditions the number 0 is added, even when specifically is conditional to add numbers if they are different from 0, I have already made invalidate caches and restart to Android Studio. Am I missing something here? Below is the code

```
 fun multiplesOf() {
        val arrayOfSelected: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()

        for (i in 0..10) {
            if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
                arrayOfSelected.add(i)
            }
        }
        Log.i("TAG", "multiplesOf: $arrayOfSelected")
    }
```

Comment: you need to realize that `0 % any number == 0`. Try changing up your condition a bit, maybe along the lines of `if (i != 0 && ( i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 ) ) {` to make it "not zero and 'divisible by 3 or 5'" instead of the current "not zero and divisible by 3 or 5" because the 'or 5' will short-circuit you every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only bug is in your boolean expression:

Given `i=0`

```kotlin
i != 0 && i % 3 == 0 // this is false
||
i % 5 == 0 // this is true
```

This is basic Bool's arithmetic: `false or true => true` and hence will execute your if's block

Adding parenthesis might help you get the desired outcome:

```kotlin
if ( i != 0 && (i % 3 == 0 || i%5 ==0) ) {...}
```

Comment: this. exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

This will evaluate to 0

```
i % 5 == 0
```

executing your

```
arrayOfSelected.add(i)
```

which will add `0`

I'd suggest add another condition to continue the loop when `i == 0`

```
if (i == 0) {
   continue
} else {
  
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
          arrayOfSelected.add(i)
    }
}
```

prints:

```
multiplesOf: [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```